# Why does this passive mixer have such a high noise figure?

Tags: noise, mixer

Here is the circuit:

[image]

And here is the noise figure as a function of frequency:

[image]

It is a big value. Why?

You can see the passive mixer here:

[image]

Comment: The diagrams are not easy to read.

Comment: please post diagrams with white background if possible

Comment: what figures would you expect? What figures are we supposed to read from the diagrams? 161dB is obviously not a noise figure of a working device, it's a mis-measrument, or a misinterpretation of something.

Comment: Looks like the *beginnings* of a mixer - but **OutN & OutP** are improperly terminated for mixing action.

Comment: @glen_geek what's missing?

Comment: @Neil_UK no more than 1 dB

Comment: No GND (or Vss) connection at **OutP, OutN**? I'd suggest a termination resistor to GND at each of these nodes. Then take output differentially: **V(OutP)-V(OutN)**.

Answer (score 0):

We know what you mean when the term *passive mixer* is used: It is a mixer with no gain component - usually employing switching devices.
One might extend the term *passive mixer* to become *linear mixer*...
The term *linear mixer* is an oxymoron - no mixing action is possible when only linear elements are involved...the desired output frequency differs from input frequency.

Tools like SPICE that calculate **noise** do so in the linear domain. The method employed cannot deal with the complex frequency space of a mixer.